# graph user api search criteria not returned normally

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

- API I requested

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?%24select=id%2CdisplayName%2CaccountEnabled%2CuserPrincipalName%2CassignedLicenses&%24top=30&%24filter=accountEnabled+eq+true&%24search=%22displayName%3Aroot%22

- I want to get the user whose displayName contains root
- The results are returned to all users

#### Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query by adding `ConsistencyLevel = eventual` in headers.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$search="displayName:root"&$filter=accountEnabled eq true&$select=displayName,accountEnabled&$top=30`